# file descriptor and loff_t offset in ioctl read and write interface

Tags: file-io, linux-kernel, ioctl

Recently i'm working on a sample code about the communication between kernel driver module and user space applications.
I have a question about the .read and .write interface in the file_operations().
According to LDD3:

```
ssize_t read(struct file *filp, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *offp);
ssize_t write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buff,size_t count, loff_t *offp);
```

> For both methods, `filp` is the file pointer and `count` is the size
>   of the requested data transfer. The `buff` argument points to the user
>   buffer holding the data to be written or the empty buffer where the
>   newly read data should be placed. Finally, `offp` is a pointer to a
>   “long offset type” object that indicates the file position the user is
>   accessing.

I'm wondering, why do we need the parameter `loff_t *offp` ? Since the element in the file descriptor: 
`filp->f_pos` already indicates the current read and write position.
And according to my observation, after the read's or write's return, the system will automatically give `filp->f_pos` the value of `offp`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

These interfaces are also used for `pread`/`pwrite` functions, which use its own offset instead of shared one `filp->f_pos`. That's why `offp` is passed to interfaces explicitely.